# VBA: Multiplying a cell with a number based on another cell in the same row

Tags: excel, vba, loops, multiple-columns, multiplication

Hope you can help out a new VBA user. My problem is, I have 2 columns, and I wan't to multiply the number of the cell in column one based on the text in another cell in the same row in column 2. This is relatively simple with in a single row, which can be solved by a function:

```
Function Function_Name(x, y)
   If y = "text_name" then Function_Name = x * 12
End Function
```

But, when I have 10 rows for example, I can't use that. I have tried creating a loop:

```
Function Function_Name(x, y)
    sumx = 0
    For i = x To x
        If y = "text1" Then sumx = x * 12
        If y = "text2" Then sumx = x * 6
        sumx = sumx + sumx
    Next i
    Function_Name = sumx
End Function
```

It is not an option to refer to any specific rows or columns (for example "B2:B12,C2:C13"), as it varies a lot with the wanted area. I want the sum of many rows, where the cell in one of the rows is multiplied with a number based on the text of another cell. I could just create a new column, use the first function and drag it down the rows, but are there not any easier ways, concerning a loop?
Thanks for reading, and have a nice day!

Comment: Do you want the result in a **third** column or do you want to **modify** the numeric column??

Comment: Why not the simple formula: `=SUMPRODUCT(B2:B12,(((C2:C12="Text1")*12)+((C2:C12="Text2")*6))`

Comment: Thank you Scott Craner! I feel grateful for your help, and silly that I couldn't figure that out my self! :D